# 3 dimensional matrix multiplication in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

For a 2-dimensional matrix A of size (N, K) with each element 'a', we can get a matrix B of size (N, K, N) with each element 'b' such that b[i, k, j] = a[i, k]*a[j,k] by the operation
`B = tf.expand_dims(A, -1)* tf.transpose(A)`.

Now with a matrix of 3-dimensional matrix A of size (M, N, K) with each element 'a', is there a way to compute **4-dimensional matrix B of size (M, N, K, N)** with each element 'b' such that
`b[m, i, k, j] = a[m, i, k]*a[m, j, k]`?

Comment: You're extremely close to the answer already - if you've matched the indices of your tensors and know the dimensions of your output, just convert it to np (or tf).einsum as in @Ehsan's answer

Answer (score 2):

Try einsum:

```
B = np.einsum('mik,mjk->mikj', A, A)
```

You can use (`tf.einsum`) if you are using tensors.

Comment: @bemma you are welcome. If this solves the issue let's accept and close the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Bemma,
This solution should work:
Expand N dimension, multiply, transpose result.

```
M, N, K = 2,3,4  # insert your dimensions here
A = tf.constant(np.random.randint(1, 100, size=[M,N,K]))  # generate A
B = tf.expand_dims(A, 1)* tf.expand_dims(A, 2)
B = tf.transpose(B, perm=[0, 1, 3, 2])

# test to verify result: 
for m in range (M):
    for i in range (N):
        for k in range (K):
            for j in range (N):
                assert B[m, i, k, j] == A[m, i, k] * A[m, j, k]
```

this test passes without errors

Comment: Thank you very much.